# Send data from backend to frontend with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a variable in Express and I'd like to retrieve it in my main javascript front file. How can I do this?

```
router.get('/app', csrfProtection, ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const favoritesArr = req.user.favorites.map(({idSave}) => idSave);
  res.render('app/fr/app', {
    favoritesArr: favoritesArr
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want to access the variable from the frontend?

Comment: `res.render` is for rendering templates and not for sending data to frontend javascript. You should use Ajax/fetch from you front end to reach `ROUTE /app` and retrieve a variable. use something like `res.send` or `res.json`

Comment: I don't know exactly, maybe with Ajax

Comment: @fedesc How exactly can I do this ? with a `$.get('/app', favoritesArr)` ?

Comment: post more info on you frontend . how do you connect your back to your front ? how do you even get to `router.get('/app'`

Comment: If your express app is writing the HTML then you can insert data in a `<script>` tag that can be read by the client